# Customize transparancy of halfeye plot in tidybayes

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, dplyr, tidyverse

I am using tidybayes to generate half-eye plot to illustrate distribution of posterior draws, following the example [here](https://mjskay.github.io/tidybayes/articles/tidy-brms.html).

With the following code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(forcats)
library(tidyr)
library(modelr)
library(tidybayes)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
library(ggridges)
library(cowplot)
library(rstan)
library(brms)
library(ggrepel)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gganimate)

theme_set(theme_tidybayes() + panel_border())

rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())

set.seed(5)
n = 10
n_condition = 5
ABC =
  tibble(
    condition = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), n),
    response = rnorm(n * 5, c(0,1,2,1,-1), 0.5)
  )

m = brm(response ~ (1|condition), data = ABC, control = list(adapt_delta = .99),
  prior = c(
    prior(normal(0, 1), class = Intercept),
    prior(student_t(3, 0, 1), class = sd),
    prior(student_t(3, 0, 1), class = sigma)
  ))

m %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_condition[condition,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_condition) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = condition, x = condition_mean, fill = stat(x < 0))) +
  stat_halfeyeh() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray80", "skyblue"))
```

I was able to generate the figure below, where negative region of each distribution was blue colored while positive regions were grey:
[image]

My desired final figure should satisfy the following criteria:

(1) Areas under distribution curve for Condition A to E are sequentially colored with "#009B9F", "#5EBCBF", "#C6DFE0", "#E9D4E2", "#D99BC5";

(2) For distribution whose posterior mean is positive (i.e., Condition A to D), assign larger alpha value (less transparent) to regions under the curve that are to the right of the 0 line and assign lower alpha value (more transparent) to regions under the curve that are to the left of the 0 line;

(3) For distribution whose posterior mean is negative (i.e., Condition E), assign lower alpha value (more transparent) 0 to regions under the curve that are to the right of the 0 line and assign higher alpha value (less transparent) to regions under the curve that are to the left of the 0 line.

I tweaked with the alpha argument in ggplot function but always failed. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are all those packages necessary for your problem? for (1) you could simply use `color` aesthetic, which would outline the plots in the given color and also provide a legend. For (2) and (3), that's not simple because they are contradictory. A possibility would be to split the data into those observations with postive and negative mean and plot them separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's tackle these one-by-one:

> (1) Areas under distribution curve for Condition A to E are
>   sequentially colored with "#009B9F", "#5EBCBF", "#C6DFE0", "#E9D4E2",
>   "#D99BC5";

Translating this into ggplot-speak, you want `condition` mapped onto the `fill` aesthetic, then you want a custom fill color scale with the values `c("#009B9F", "#5EBCBF", "#C6DFE0", "#E9D4E2", "#D99BC5")`.

(I'll put comments in each block where something has changed)

```r
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_condition[condition,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_condition) %>%
  # map condition onto fill here ------------------------\/
  ggplot(aes(y = condition, x = condition_mean, fill = condition)) +
  stat_halfeyeh() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  # change the fill scale to use your values ------------\/
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009B9F", "#5EBCBF", "#C6DFE0", "#E9D4E2", "#D99BC5"))
```

[image: plot with manual fill scale]

Sidebar: I'm not sure I would use a manual color scale for this: it's usually easier and better to use pre-made color scales from places like [Viridis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html), [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=3), or [HCL Wizard](http://hclwizard.org/) --- these color scales are designed for things like colorblind safety, perceptual uniformity, good desaturation, etc. Also this example uses categorical data and the color scale you provided has a natural order to it; I hope your real data is ordinal and not categorical, as otherwise the color scale implies an ordering that does not exist in the data.

Anyway, the next question:

> (2) For distribution whose posterior mean is positive (i.e., Condition
>   A to D), assign larger alpha value (less transparent) to regions under
>   the curve that are to the right of the 0 line and assign lower alpha
>   value (more transparent) to regions under the curve that are to the
>   left of the 0 line;
>
> (3) For distribution whose posterior mean is negative (i.e., Condition
>   E), assign lower alpha value (more transparent) 0 to regions under the
>   curve that are to the right of the 0 line and assign higher alpha
>   value (less transparent) to regions under the curve that are to the
>   left of the 0 line.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean here, so I'm going to try two different things.

One possibility is this: you want to map the `x` value onto the `alpha` aesthetic, but you want to reverse this relationship if the mean of `condition_mean` is less than 0 (I'll actually use the `slab_alpha` aesthetic, which specifically targets the slab portion of this geom and leaves the intervals alone). I'll start by doing the straightforward `slab_alpha` mapping:

```r
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_condition[condition,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_condition) %>%
  # map x value onto alpha -------------------------------------------\/
  ggplot(aes(y = condition, x = condition_mean, fill = condition, slab_alpha = stat(x))) +
  stat_halfeyeh() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009B9F", "#5EBCBF", "#C6DFE0", "#E9D4E2", "#D99BC5"))
```

[image: simple slab_alpha mapping]

Immediately you should see a problem: your manual color scale also uses the alpha channel, and these two mappings combine in a confusing way. So I am going to switch to a color palette from ColorBrewer that does not use the alpha channel:

```r
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_condition[condition,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_condition) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = condition, x = condition_mean, fill = condition, slab_alpha = stat(x))) +
  stat_halfeyeh() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  # categorical palette that doesn't vary alpha much:
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: alpha with color brewer palette]

For the next part, you have to split the alpha mapping in two (I don't think it is possible to do this without splitting the data, as ggplot currently does not support mixing columns from the original data with columns computed by a statistic). You can pass functions (including purrr-style `~` functions) to the `data` argument of stats and geoms and these functions are applied to the data, which allows you to easily split up the data inside ggplot. In addition, because `spread_draws` groups by all indices in the expression you pass it (in this case, `conditions`), the data are already grouped by `condition`, so an expression like `mean(condition_mean)` will calculate the mean of `condition_mean` within each level of `condition`. That allows you to do something like this:

```r
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_condition[condition,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_condition) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = condition, x = condition_mean, fill = condition)) +
  # move alpha mapping here and split halfeye spec in two
  stat_halfeyeh(aes(slab_alpha = stat(x)), data = ~ filter(., mean(condition_mean) > 0)) +
  stat_halfeyeh(aes(slab_alpha = -stat(x)), data = ~ filter(., mean(condition_mean) < 0)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: split alpha, continuous]

Alternatively, you might have been asking for a hard change in alpha value. For that you just want something like `stat(x < 0)` or `stat(x > 0)` instead of `stat(x)` or 
`-stat(x)`:

```r
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_condition[condition,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_condition) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = condition, x = condition_mean, fill = condition)) +
  # use binary alpha mapping
  stat_halfeyeh(aes(slab_alpha = stat(x > 0)), data = ~ filter(., mean(condition_mean) > 0)) +
  stat_halfeyeh(aes(slab_alpha = stat(x < 0)), data = ~ filter(., mean(condition_mean) < 0)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: split alpha, binary]

Finally, in general if you are trying to use alpha to emphasize things that are more likely far from 0 on either side, I would be inclined not to define that mapping on the basis of which side the mean is on --- it seems a little backwards to ignore the uncertainty to decide which side it is on on the bases of the mean alone.

Here's a simpler alternative that just encodes distance from 0 (i.e. `abs(x)`) on the alpha aesthetic:

```r
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_condition[condition,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_condition) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = condition, x = condition_mean, fill = condition)) +

  # use alpha mapping with abs(x)
  stat_halfeyeh(aes(slab_alpha = stat(abs(x)))) +

  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: alpha channel on distance from 0]

Comment: Amazing answer! My intention was to facilitate interpretation of the probability that a coefficient is greater/smaller than 0. Comparing the relative proportion of solid and transparent area for condition A would hint that the probability for coefficient of A greater than 0 is roughly 80%. While I agree encoding by distance from 0 is a better idea, I'd like to learn more why this is not recommended. According to my limited knowledge, being able to interpretate coef. probablistically like above is also an advantage of Bayesian. But indeed as u mentioned, problems may arise for coef. close to 0

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! In that case my recommendation might be to do something like `fill = stat(x > 0)` - you don't necessarily need condition mapped onto fill since condition is already easy to see on the y axis. My concern with using alpha for this was that it makes one side more salient than the other, so I worry it could downplay uncertainty rather than emphasize it.